# Table count from 1 and up

Tags: php

I have a table on my website, where I basically want to count from 1 and up to 100 (100 is my amount of rows in the table), so basically it will look like this

```
Rank | Player     | Kills | Deaths  
===================================
   1 | ImSchnebz  |   100 |      24  
   2 | BedRockets |   45  |     485
```

and so on..

How would I do that with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating:

```
$c_rank = 0;
echo "Rank | Player | Kills | Deaths" . PHP_EOL;
for($ranks as $rank)
{
    $c_rank += 1;
    printf("%s | %s | %s | %s" . PHP_EOL, $c_rank, $ranks['player'], $ranks['kills'], $ranks['deaths']);
}
```

assuming those array keys exist in your players table.
(AND assuming you give the proper formatting. I did not give you the HTML formatting, but just the counter).